# Error when running gulp for transcompiling es6 to es5

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-babel

I have a simple javascript file like this:

```
'use strict';

const sentences = [
    {subject: 'Javascript', verb: 'is', object: 'great'}
    {subject: 'Elephants', verb: 'are', object: 'large'}
];

function say ({subject, verb, object}){
    console.log(`${subject} ${verb} ${object}`);
}

for(let s of sentences){
    say(s);
}
```

And i`ve installed gulp for transcompiling purposes. Here's my gulp file:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const babel = require('gulp-babel');

gulp.task('default', function(){
    gulp.src("es6/**/*.js").pipe(babel()).pipe(gulp.dest("dist"));
    gulp.src("public/es6/**/*.js").pipe(babel()).pipe(gulp.dest("public/dist"));
});
```

My javascript file is inside a 'es6' and a 'public/es6' folders. So when i run the gulp command, it should work, but it gives me these errors instead:

```
Joaos-MacBook-Air:chapter2 joaovictor$ gulp
[12:44:06] Using gulpfile ~/Desktop/javascript/chapter2/gulpfile.js
[12:44:06] Starting 'default'...
[12:44:06] Finished 'default' after 12 ms

events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
SyntaxError: /Users/joaovictor/Desktop/javascript/chapter2/.babelrc: Error while parsing JSON - Unexpected ''
    at JSON5.parse.error (/Users/joaovictor/Desktop/javascript/chapter2/node_modules/gulp-babel/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/json5/lib/json5.js:50:25)
    at JSON5.parse.word (/Users/joaovictor/Desktop/javascript/chapter2/node_modules/gulp-babel/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/json5/lib/json5.js:378:13)
    at JSON5.parse.value (/Users/joaovictor/Desktop/javascript/chapter2/node_modules/gulp-babel/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/json5/lib/json5.js:478:56)
    at Object.parse (/Users/joaovictor/Desktop/javascript/chapter2/node_modules/gulp-babel/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/json5/lib/json5.js:491:18)
    at OptionManager.addConfig (/Users/joaovictor/Desktop/javascript/chapter2/node_modules/gulp-babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:225:62)
    at OptionManager.findConfigs (/Users/joaovictor/Desktop/javascript/chapter2/node_modules/gulp-babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:436:16)
    at OptionManager.init (/Users/joaovictor/Desktop/javascript/chapter2/node_modules/gulp-babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:484:12)
    at File.initOptions (/Users/joaovictor/Desktop/javascript/chapter2/node_modules/gulp-babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:223:65)
    at new File (/Users/joaovictor/Desktop/javascript/chapter2/node_modules/gulp-babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:140:24)
    at Pipeline.transform (/Users/joaovictor/Desktop/javascript/chapter2/node_modules/gulp-babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:46:16)
```

What am i missing here?

Comment: The error indicates that your `.babelrc` has malformed JSON. What are its contents?

Comment: See [the `gulp-babel` repo](https://github.com/babel/gulp-babel#install) for information on providing configuration options to `gulp-babel`. Since you're trying to use ES2015 syntax, you'll want to install `babel-preset-es2015` and specify it as a `preset` for Babel.

Comment: My .babelrc file was empty. And i remember setting it correctly. That's why it was causing this error. I've set it up again and now it's working. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Cool. Glad you're back up and running.

Answer (score 0):

I think some of the packages were not installed or compatible, regardless of that, you should make sure all dev-dependencies are installed , source code are available on Babel documentation website [https://babeljs.io/setup];
so your package.json file and .baberlc file should look like this:

```
{
  "name": "nu",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.3",
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-babel": "^8.0.0-beta.2"
  }
}
```

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

so run your code...it should work just fine!!!